# Hyperlink to call action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to figure out a trivial creation of a hyperlink (either through using an Html.ActionLink or plain hyperlink markup) to call a certain controller action and pass in a userId

In have a controller with an Index action.  I have a hyperlink in another unrelated view where I need to all that controller's index action and pass in a userId which is param in the action method.

Update:

```
Html.ActionLink("Test Something", "Index", "Tests", new { @userId = @Model.User.UserId }, null)
```

that is an example of what I tried.  Problem is, it's not showing Tests/ in the url when I moue over the url during runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ActionLink helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) from any view anywhere in the application:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "call index",            // linkText
    "index",                 // action
    "home",                  // controller
    new { userid = "123" },  // routeValue
    null                     // htmlAttributes
)
```

Assuming default routes this should generate:

```
<a href="/?userid=123">call index</a>
```

Comment: your second assumes you're on the homepage calling the index action method of the homepage?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, no, it doesn't assume anything like this. You can use this helper from absolutely any view in your application and it will generate this markup (assuming the default routes are setup - default route look like this `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and if controller is not specified it falls back to `Home` and if action is not specified it falls back to `Index`).

Comment: The problem is when the link renders with your suggestion, I mouse over it and it's only showing me the url of the same view I'm on.  It doesn't show me Tests/

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, what `Tests` are you talking about? Is this the name of some controller or something? How does your link look like? How does your routes look like?

Comment: Updated the question, check out the syntax I'm using

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, I don't understand what's the problem. If in your route you have defined that that the default action of a controller is `Index` (it's the default when you create a new project, look at your RegisterRoutes and you will see a constraint saying `action="Index"`), it's perfectly normal that this will generate `Tests/` as url and not `Tests/Index`. Both will anyway point to exactly the same controller action.

Comment: I am saying it's not generating Tests.  For example this hyperlink is showing /Dashboard when I mouse over it not /Tests

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, are you using areas or something? I mean you are not showing any code, not explaining anything about your setup, I can only be throwing wild guesses here.

Comment: <a href="Testing/@Model.tUser.UserId">Test</a>  When I add this it shows Testing/21 which seems like a valid route but then doesn't hit my TestingController's Index(int userId) action method

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, do you have a route like this: `{controller}/{action}/{userid}`? I doubt it. I bet you have `{controller}/{action}/{id}`. Notice the difference? The reason yuour action isn't hit is because if you don't have a route which takes `userid` as route parameter an exception will be thrown telling you that `userid` hasn't been specified. Also absolutely never hardcode an url as you did in an ASP.NET MVC application. Never write anything like `<a href="Testing/@Model.tUser.UserId">Test</a>`. Always use Html.ActionLink to generate your links.

Comment: this is the only way I was able to get it to work <a href="Testing?userId=@Model.User.UserId">Test</a>

Comment: Yep I was missing an explicit route which was the main problem.  Thanks.  We are explicitly setting routes for each controller/index in a Routes.cs